# How to enumerate HSQLDB catalogs for clean, scripted shutdown

Tags: scripting, hsqldb

I'd like to script the clean shutdown of an HSQLDB 2.0.0-rc9 "Listener" (server).

**Is there a way to interrogate an HSQLDB server to determine the catalogs (databases) it is currently serving, either via `sqltool` or HSQL client programming?**

Background:  If I understand correctly, safely shutting down an HSQLDB "Listener" process (an `org.hsqldb.server.Server`) requires closing each served catalog (database) with a SHUTDOWN command.  Presently, the *NIX init scripts shipped with HSQLDB require the administrator to maintain *a separate list of catalogs* to be shut down, introducing the possibility of error by misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:  this question is misguided.

Even if I could enumerate catalogs served by an HSQLDB "Listener" (server), I'd still need a privileged login -- one per catalog -- to issue the SHUTDOWN commands.  Thus, there would still be the need for external config information, which is what I wish to avoid.

SIGTERM support would be a lot easier.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Though you do still need to maintain a list of URLIDs, the clean-shutdown use case is supported on UNIX with a provided init script which is documented at http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/unix-chapt.html#uxc_daemon.

Pilcrow appears to be a UNIX user since he is advocating SIGTERM support.

Comment: Right, this is no different than the circumstance that prompted me to ask this question originally.  Maintaining URLIDs is the same as maintaining a separate list of catalogs.